# Swift - enumerateChildNodesWithName with name containing a string

Tags: swift, nodes, contains, enumerate, child-nodes

I would like to use enumerateChildNodesWithName but enumerateChildNodesWithName containing another string, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") { node, _ in
if node.name == "string" {
    // do anything
}}
```